# Loading images into canvas using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to animate images into a canvas using JavaScript. Everything seems to be going as expected in the console but the image won't load onto the canvas. Here is my code

```
<body>
    <canvas id="gameDisplay">

    </canvas>
</body>
<script>
    var canvas = null;
    var context = null;
    var frameRate = 1000 / 30;
    var frame = 0;
    var assets = [
        'images/char.png',
        'images/char1.png'
    ];
    var frames = [];

    var onImageLoad = function() {
        console.log('IMAGE!!');
    };

    var setup = function() {
        canvas = document.getElementById('gameDisplay');
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        for (var i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
            frames.push(new Image());
            frames[i].src = assets[i];
            frames[i].onload = onImageLoad;

        }
    };
    var animate = function() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.drawImage(frames[frame], 192, 192);
        frame = (frame + 1) % frames.length;
    }
    setup();
</script>
```

The project is located [here](http://billischill.ddns.net/gameQuest).

Comment: Are you missing a `window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)` call?

Comment: im not sure im kinda new to this could you please explain

Comment: Your `animate` method never gets called, so the images get loaded, but never get drawn. You need to schedule the `animate` method. One way is putting `window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)` at the end of both `setup` and `animate`. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations for an example.

Comment: that loads the first image but the second image isnt showing is it because i have just 2 and its going so fast that i cant see the other

Comment: You should figure out when to show images when using `window.requestAnimationFrame`, by keeping track of time in some way. For testing, you can use `setTimeout(animate, 1000)` in `setup`. That will make it call `animate` every second. However, this now gets into a different question - probably worth playing with the examples first to get the idea how it works at the basic level, then adding more complexity. Hope this helps.

Comment: i made a console log to tell me when it was doing the animation request and it shows that the one put under the animate function keeps requesting but the one under the setup function only request twice

Comment: it runs really good at the begining but then it get really slow and seems like its going to crash the browser on every device i use

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer when you have two versions of your code; the code in the question and different code on the linked site in your comment below.  You are trying to implement the Udacity course and I see two spots where you are not following the instructions.
1- .onload must be set before .src
2- setInterval gets called in setup not animate
I made these changes and got a basic animation to work although I could not download your images because it kept crashing my browser.
See video #13 in the course videos.

I think you need to read the canvas and animation docs, try these
[MDN canvas api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_AP)
You are not getting the canvas correctly and once you do you can call drawImage.
Also, for animation look into requestAnimationFrame(),  try this to get
you started.
[requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: its not loading my other images just the last one in the array?

Comment: is it bad to animate like this because i added the setTimeout to it and it loaded all of my images!! but it gets slow after a while and just doesnt work well on edge

Comment: well the link in your question has different code than the code in your question.  First I would refactor this using requestAnimationFrame it is not that hard.  Anyway you are using setTimeout in the animate function (on the live site) crashes on my machine after a few minutes.  If you are loading some image but not all then you are not looping through the array correctly.  Why are you using modulus in the index of the frame array.  Actually, I don't see the point of frame array when you could just use the asset array in drawImage.  Honestly, I think you need to start over.

Comment: well could you please help me sir i am new to this and really want to learn this so i could have an animated character and make him move across the screen.

Comment: if it helps [this is what i was trying to get to work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80t1u5J4Y1o&list=PLAwxTw4SYaPlUUkh6txMRXE-w-6N1Z225&index=5)